# Requiring files from dependencies via RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using requirejs and have a file I'd like to import from one of my dependencies.

Here is my folder structure

> - src
>
>   - my_app
>   - require_config
> - node_modules
>
>   - other_repo
>
>     - apps
>     - components
>
>       - camera_component
>       - camera_view
>     - require_config

Let's say in `my_app` I load Camera Component.

node_modules/other_repo/components/camera_component.js:

```
define(function(require) {

    var CameraView = require('components/camera_view');

    ....

    return MyClass;

});
```

The problem is that `components/camera_view` doesn't exist in my path. It does however exist in that project. If this were one or 2 dependencies I needed to shim or tweak I would just modify `paths` within require config; however, there are a lot of dependencies. There is an entire require config for that project which I should probably respect.

Is there a solution for this sort of problem within requirejs? Should I fork that repo or only use some package thats been prepared for external use.

Comment: please add require_config code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Require it using a relative path:

```
var CameraView = require('./camera_view');
```

Since the two files are in the same directory, the `require` call will resolve the path as the `camera_view` module which is in the same path as `camera_component`.

This will work for all cases where your modules exist in specific locations relative to one another.

Comment: I found another solution as well. Namely the "package" option in requirejs. It essentially lets you specify a new baseUrl for some folder.